# php 8.2 + laravel 9 failed with composer error that cron-expression does not match the constraint

Tags: laravel, composer-php, php-8

I am updating laravel to use php 8.2, according to [laravel document here](https://blog.laravel.com/laravel-loves-php-82), using "laravel/framework": "^9.43" should be enough.

[image: php 8.2 & larvel 9]

My composer.json are the following,

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.2",
    "clue/socket-raw": "^1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "gregwar/captcha": "1.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^5.1",
    "jacobcyl/ali-oss-storage": "^2.0",
    "james-heinrich/getid3": "^1.9",
    "laravel/framework": "^9.43",
    "laravel/horizon": "^5.7",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "php-curl-class/php-curl-class": "^8.6"
},
```

But when running `composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader --no-dev` (I don't use composer.lock here), composer complained,

> laravel/framework[v9.43.0, ..., 9.x-dev] require dragonmantank/cron-expression ^3.3.2 -> found
> dragonmantank/cron-expression[dev-set-up-semaphore,
> dev-update-v3-php8, dev-master, dev-issue/35-fix-and-or-problem,
> dev-allow-phpstan-failures, v1.0.0, ..., v1.2.1, v2.0.0, ...,
> v2.3.1.x-dev, v3.0.0, ..., v3.3.1] but it does not match the
> constraint.

I know laravel/framework 9 requires cron-expression ^3.3.2 as https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/framework said. But I can't figure out which other package requires a different version of cron-expression. I search the old composer.lock (which I don't use when install) I find multi-mention of `dev-master`, but no [dev-set-up-semaphore, dev-update-v3-php8, dev-issue/35-fix-and-or-problem, dev-allow-phpstan-failures]

Please check the following build log

[image: composer error]

How do I find that package ? BTW, php 8.1.7 + "laravel/framework" 8 works fine.

--- update ---

I find the reason why composer complains.

I have "require-dev" in my composer and all packages in it use the latest versions! I also check https://packagist.org/ to make sure they all say they support ^8.0. Besides, my command is `composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader --no-dev`,  **no-dev** !

So I didn't expect "require-dev" will cause problem. But only after I remove the `"require-dev"` did composer run successfully!

Apparently one of those packages do not support php 8.2 yet.

```
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.17",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.21.0",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.18.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.5.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.28"
}
```

After removing "facade/ignition" from "require-dev", composer finally works!

As for why does "facade/ignition" cause the problem and what is the solution for it, please refer to @NicoHaase's answer and my discussion with him.

Comment: Please can you add your entire `composer.json` file.

Comment: That looks strange - packagist.org lists that package version. Can you share more details? Also, Composer always tells you which packages cause the problem, as you can see in the given message

Comment: Because I used `composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader --no-dev` so what I list, the require block is basically the composer.json.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with **all** error message

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question in text form. Also, did you check whether any caches are used? Whether Composer is run in the most current version?

Comment: Well, you've posted a screenshot of text content, which should be shared **in text form**. Also, as packagist.org lists v3.3.2 of that given package, I try to understand why your build server isn't using that information. Sharing more details (like whether any cache is used, or which version of Composer you use) might help

Comment: "Do not run Composer as root/super user" - why not do that? What did you change to get to that second error output? And what did you try to resolve it? Also, why not use `composer.lock`  as recommended in tons of tutorials?

Comment: Change from `composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader --no-dev` to `composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader --no-dev --no-cache --version --verbose`, i.e. add `--no-cache --version --verbose`

Comment: Well. Using `--version` disables the installation of packages. That also explains why there is no output of any resolved pacakges. Without that flag, and with the given list of required packages, I cannot reproduce your problem. Packages are installed as expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251192/discussion-between-qiulang-and-nico-haase).

Comment: @NicoHaase I find the reason but I don't know why!  I have "require-dev" block in my real composer.json. But all packages in my "require-dev" block uses the latest version and I also check their readme, they all say they support ^8.0. But only I remove "require-dev" block completely I can run composer successfully. I will update my question.

Comment: @NicoHaase So I have found who to be blame, "facade/ignition". Remove it from "require-dev" block, composer works.

Comment: " I have "require-dev" block in my real composer.json" - why didn't you share that initially?

Comment: Because I run `composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader --no-dev` I had though `--no-dev` then what I write in "require-dev" does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Apparently one of those packages do not support php 8.2 yet." - no, that's not the cause. Ignition does not support Laravel v9, as written in their readme:

> If you're on Laravel 8 or above, you can switch to spatie/laravel-ignition, which is a drop-in replacement. Replace facade/ignition with "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0" in your application's composer.json file.
>
> Going forward, we'll only add security fixes to facade/ignition and highly encourage you to switch to spatie/laravel-ignition.

Comment: Thanks for spending time in investigating it. Sorry I didn't add `"require-dev"` because I didn't know composer would check it even I said `composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader --no-dev`, coming from nodejs background I find that quite surprising.

Comment: Even with `"spatie/laravel-ignition":"^1.6.4"` composer still fails.  spatie/laravel-ignition 1.6.4 requires spatie/ignition ^1.4.1 -> found spatie/ignition[dev-dependabot/github_actions/ramsey/composer-install-2, dev-dependabot/github_actions/actions/setup-node-3, dev-dependabot/github_actions/actions/cache-3, dev-dependabot/github_actions/actions/checkout-3, dev-main, dev-old, dev-l10, dev-shift-52829, 0.0.1, ..., 0.0.8, 1.0.0, ..., 1.3.1] but it does not match the constraint.

Comment: I give it up. It just doesn't worth the effort.

Comment: Do you use any different package source than packagist.org? It lists the other versions

Comment: I use its China mirror https://developer.aliyun.com/composer

Comment: check here https://packagist.org/mirrors

Comment: That's information you should have shared earlier. Did you check whether the installation works if you use the original sources?

Comment: No as I said I gave it up. I just remove that package from "require-dev", after all I don't use it and everything works fine again.

Comment: I actually raised an issue to them https://github.com/spatie/laravel-ignition/issues/133. But my issue was closed immediately,  a typical way that laravel guys handle the issues. They always close issues immediately. That is one of reasons I think why bother?!

Comment: You raised an issue with Spatie because any unofficial mirror is not working as expected? Why not ask whoever maintains that mirror?

Comment: After I discussed with you I removed the mirror setting from my composer.json but the result was the same. composer complained the same error.

Comment: Besides, that is NOT unofficial mirror. That is one of official mirrors in China as packagist.org/mirrors suggests!

Comment: Are you sure? The mirror page lists some "official" ones they run on their own, and the list that shows the one you use is under the headline "aware of the following list of third-party-run mirrors" - third party, not official, not run by them

Comment: Also, are you sure you haven't configured that mirror on a global level?

Comment: Technically it is not the mirror packagist.org maintains so I guess you can say it is unofficial mirror but every php developer I know in China uses that

Comment: "Why bother" - because others cannot reproduce the problem. To me, this still sounds like a misbehaving, unofficial mirror of Packagist

Comment: OK since you are so persistent let me check if I have set the mirror on global level.

Comment: How did you find out I use  other source when you said "Do you use any different package source than packagist.org? It lists the other versions" What other version it lists ? I didn't see that.

Comment: The output of requiring `spatie/laravel-ignition:^1.6.4`  does list v1.3.1 as the latest version available for `spatie/ignition`, while https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/ignition shows to more versions of that package (namely v1.4.0 and v1.4.1). If your package source does not contain these two versions, it's obvious that you cannot install them

Comment: OK I did find we set set the mirror on global level on the build server, so you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Use `composer`'s why-not command:

```
composer why-not laravel/framework 9.43
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase if you check the docs... https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#prohibits-why-not

"tells you which packages are blocking a given package from being installed. Specify a version constraint to verify whether upgrades can be performed in your project, and if not why not"